# routerConfig parameter not defined for GetMaterialApp flutter

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-getx, state-management, auto-route

I have to use GetX for state management in an application where I have been routing with autoroutes. I have returned this in my main.dart file - MyApp class.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});
  final _appRouter = AppRouter();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => PwCubit(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => ConfirmPwCubit()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => SignInBloc()),
        // BlocProvider(create: (_)=> AuthenticationBloc(authenticationRepository: authenticationRepository, userRepository: userRepository),),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => TransactionBloc()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => ProfileInfoBloc())
      ],
      child: MaterialApp.router(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
        themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.green,
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.green)),
        // routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(),
        routerConfig: _appRouter.config(),
        // home: SignupPage()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, I have to use getx inside this(for dark theme). But the GetMaterialApp doesn't have an argument called routerConfig.

This is my routes.dart file

```
  @AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: "Route")
class AppRouter extends $AppRouter {
  @override
  RouteType get defaultRouteType => RouteType.material();
  @override
  final List<AutoRoute> routes = [
    // AutoRoute(page: SignupPageRoute.page, path: "/", initial: true),
    AutoRoute(page: HomePageRoute.page, path: "/"), // (/home)
    AutoRoute(page: LoginPageRoute.page, path: "/login"),
  ];
}
```

Since, this is a task given to me in my internship, I have to use autoroutes and getx for this even though I have bloc already provided for managing state. I have seen people use the routerDelegate argument(which is avilaible in GetMaterialApp) instead of routerConfig but I don't know how to modify the routes.dart file after that.